# Paramiko and ssh2-python3 not working as expected in high threads

Tags: python, security, ssh, python-multithreading, paramiko

I wanted to create a SSH Checker that checks for user passwords of some servers using Python.
I'm aware that using it for nefarious tool is illegal but I'm creating it for research and learning purposes. (Mainly learning the nitty gritty of threading and security).

What caught me very curious is the fact that it kinda imposes limitations to number of connections and I want to find out why and how.

I've used paramiko and ssh2-python3 and both of them don't work correctly while executing in high threads. (I'm talking about 200, 500 or even 1000)

### What did I try?

For paramiko I used it in 20 threads and for ssh2-python3 I used it in 50/60 ish threads.

### What happened?

When using paramiko I got some errors relating to SSH Banner (Even though my computers are in my local network).

The problem mainly starts with 12 threads.
Seems like paramiko doesn't like multi-threading.

`paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner`

This is part of the exception

```
Exception (client): Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/d3f4u1t/Work/Programming_2/Python/Labs/Lab10_SSH/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2292, in \_check_banner
buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/d3f4u1t/Work/Programming_2/Python/Labs/Lab10_SSH/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 374, in readline
buf += self.\_read_timeout(timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/d3f4u1t/Work/Programming_2/Python/Labs/Lab10_SSH/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 603, in \_read_timeout
raise EOFError()
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/d3f4u1t/Work/Programming_2/Python/Labs/Lab10_SSH/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2113, in run
self.\_check_banner()
File "/home/d3f4u1t/Work/Programming_2/Python/Labs/Lab10_SSH/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2296, in \_check_banner
raise SSHException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

and the exception goes on and on, repeating as it checks more and more...
```

Even though these exceptions were happening I was getting a few successful matches, it is unreliable and I highly suspect it is because of threading.

For ssh2-python3 it stops reporting successful matches after 50/60 ish threads.

### What did I expect?

I expected them to work as expected in high threads but they did not.

### Main questions

1. What is the problem happening here?
2. What are the ways to fix this problem?

## Edit 1:

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

### paramiko

I get lots of exceptions here...

- Edit 2: Changed the code so it randomly connects to multiple ips but the banner errors won't stop

```
import random
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import product

import paramiko


def paramiko_core(server, port, username, password):
    cli = paramiko.SSHClient()
    cli.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        cli.connect(
            server,
            port,
            username,
            password,
            banner_timeout=150,
        )
        cli.close()
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        ...


# Put some dummy or safe ips in the file (I put about 40 or so)
with open("sv_list.txt") as f:
    list_ips = f.readlines()
# And put a valid ip address here
list_ips.insert(20, "127.0.0.1")
# Replace a valid username here...
list_username = ["user1", "user2", "real_user", "user3", "user4", "user5"]
# Replace a valid password here...
list_password = ["pass1", "pass2", "real_pass", "pass3", "pass4", "pass5"]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
    comb_list = list(product(list_ips, list_username, list_password))
    random.shuffle(comb_list)
    for ip, username, password in comb_list:
        executor.submit(paramiko_core, ip.strip(), 22, username, password)
```

### ssh2-python3

I get inconsistent results whether the max_worker is high or low.
Though it gets more inconsistent the higher I set it.

- Edit 2: I changed to connect to multiple ip and it definitely improved, but not 100% reliable. 8 time out of 10 it reports correctly.
- So it probably had to do with too many connections to a single server.

```
import random
import socket
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import product

from ssh2.exceptions import (
    AuthenticationError,
    SocketDisconnectError,
    SocketRecvError,
    Timeout,
)
from ssh2.session import Session


def ssh2_core(server, port, username, password):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(4)

    try:
        sock.connect((server, port))
    except OSError:
        return False

    session = Session()
    session.set_timeout(1000)

    try:
        session.handshake(sock)
        session.userauth_password(username, password)
        session.open_session()
    except Timeout:
        return False
    except SocketRecvError:
        return False
    except SocketDisconnectError:
        return False
    except AuthenticationError:
        return False

    return True


# Put some dummy or safe ips in the file (I put about 40 or so)
with open("sv_list.txt") as f:
    list_ips = f.readlines()
# And put a valid ip address here
list_ips.insert(20, "127.0.0.1")

list_username = [
    *[f"user{i}" for i in range(3)],
    "real_user",  # Replace a valid username here...
    *[f"user{i}" for i in range(3)],
]

list_password = [
    *[f"pass{i}" for i in range(3)],
    "real_pass",  # Replace a valid password here...
    *[f"pass{i}" for i in range(3)],
]

result = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=120) as executor:
    comb_list = list(product(list_ips, list_username, list_password))
    random.shuffle(comb_list)
    for ip, username, password in comb_list:
        result.append(executor.submit(ssh2_core, ip.strip(), 22, username, password))

if True in [rslt.result() for rslt in result]:
    print("This time it worked!")
else:
    print("This time it failed!")
```

Comment: We need [mcve].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl +1. I've added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Isn't this rather about your server not being able (or refusing) to handle so many connections opening at nearly the same time?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for pointing out to this problem. It somehow improved the rate of success but paramiko still complains about SSH protocol banner. I don't know how to fix it or if it is a harmless error.